# PowerShell Where-Object date format

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find errors in the system log only logged after the 1st of July 2011:

```
Get-EventLog system -entrytype error | Where-Object {$_.Time -ge [datetime]"01/07/2011 9:00 AM"}
```

However this doesn't return anything. Is the format of my Where-Object correct?

Comment: Just for information: $_.Time doesn't exist! Using $_.TimeGenerated do the job rigth!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `-After` parameter:

```
Get-EventLog system -entrytype error -After "01/07/2011 9:00 AM"
```

Comment: Thats so much simpler! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
  $a = (get-date).AddDays(-1); 
  Get-EventLog -logname system -entrytype warning,error -after $a
```

This snippet will give you every warning or error in the event log since yesterday at 12:01 am.